# client-server approach using realm with swift xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, client-server, realm

I'm new to xcode, swift, and realm. And i have to build an IOS application for my graduation project. I have a problem on how to handle multiple clients request. my application is suppose to get requests from multiple users and i have to handle these requests in a server (start counters, a timer, or add, delete, update, etc), and my server is using the realm database. my question is how to communicate between a client and a server locally ? and can i implement the server with swift not javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Realm Mobile Platform for your client to server interactions, you should be able to use the event handling features of the Realm Object Server to detect and respond to requests triggered by users. You can [download a trial of the Professional Edition](https://realm.io/pricing/realm-professional-edition/) (Which should be enough for your needs as a private project.)

The code for registering an event handler looks like this (Taken from [the Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/#event-handling) page)

```
var Realm = require('realm');

// Insert the Realm admin token here
//   Linux:  cat /etc/realm/admin_token.base64
//   macOS:  cat realm-object-server/admin_token.base64
var ADMIN_TOKEN = 'ADMIN_TOKEN';

// the URL to the Realm Object Server
var SERVER_URL = 'realm://127.0.0.1:9080';

// The regular expression you provide restricts the observed Realm files to only the subset you
// are actually interested in. This is done in a separate step to avoid the cost
// of computing the fine-grained change set if it's not necessary.
var NOTIFIER_PATH = '/^\/([0-9a-f]+)\/private$/';

// The handleChange callback is called for every observed Realm file whenever it
// has changes. It is called with a change event which contains the path, the Realm,
// a version of the Realm from before the change, and indexes indication all objects
// which were added, deleted, or modified in this change
function handleChange(changeEvent) {
  // Extract the user ID from the virtual path, assuming that we're using
  // a filter which only subscribes us to updates of user-scoped Realms.
  var matches = changeEvent.path.match(/^\/([0-9a-f]+)\/private$/);
  var userId = matches[1];

  var realm = changeEvent.realm;
  var coupons = realm.objects('Coupon');
  var couponIndexes = changeEvent.changes.Coupon.insertions;

  for (var couponIndex in couponIndexes) {
    var coupon = coupons[couponIndex];
    if (coupon.isValid !== undefined) {
      var isValid = verifyCouponForUser(coupon, userId);
      // Attention: Writes here will trigger a subsequent notification.
      // Take care that this doesn't cause infinite changes!
      realm.write(function() {
        coupon.isValid = isValid;
      });
    }
  }
}

// create the admin user
var adminUser = Realm.Sync.User.adminUser(adminToken);

// register the event handler callback
Realm.Sync.addListener(SERVER_URL, adminUser, NOTIFIER_PATH, 'change', handleChange);

console.log('Listening for Realm changes');
```

Unfortunately, there's no support for Realm and Swift on the server at this point (Unless it's a Mac server) since Realm Swift needs the Objective-C runtime to work, and this isn't available on non-Mac platforms. Node.js is the way to go. :)